Measurability of a family of parametric integrals assuming measurability of the integrand w.r.t. the parameter
Let $D$ and $E$ be measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ respectively, and $v : (x,t) \in D \times E \mapsto v(x,t) \in \mathbb{C}$.
Assume that the maps $v(\cdot, t)$, $t \in E$ belong to $L^p(D)$, $p \in [1, +\infty)$.
Finally, let $p^\ast$ denote the Hölder conjugate of $p$ (i.e. $\frac1p + \frac1{p^\ast} = 1$), and define for $g \in L^{p^\ast}(D)$ the map:
$$G : t \in E \mapsto \int_D g(x) v(x,t)\mathrm{d}x \in \mathbb{C}$$
I would like to figure out if only imposing separate or at most joint measurability on $v$ would be sufficient to obtain the measurability of $G$, or if you need some better assumptions. I don't really see an easy way to go at it using the definition of a measurable function, but I can't really think of a good construction with a pointwise limit or sup/inf of (countably many) known measurable functions, but I'm surely missing something simple or obvious as per usual.
For context, this arises when looking at the weak measurability of the map $t \in D \mapsto v(\cdot,t) \in L^p(D)$ as a Banach-valued map, as the linear functionals on $L^p(D)$ are exactly the maps of the form $u \in L^p(D) \mapsto \int_D g(x) u(x)\mathrm{d}x$ for $g \in L^{p^\ast}$.
A map $f : E \to X$ a Banach space is said to be weakly measurable if the maps $t \in E \mapsto \Lambda(f(t))$, $\Lambda \in X^\ast$ are measurable in the usual sense, and so replacing $X$ by $L^p(D)$ and $f$ by $t \mapsto v(\cdot, t)$ yields the problem at hand.
With this point of view, one of the easiest assumptions to work with would be continuity of $t \mapsto v(\cdot, t)$, because then $\Lambda \circ v : E \to \mathbb{C}$, $\Lambda \in L^p(D)^\ast$ is continuous and scalar-valued, thus measurable. However this is a bit strong of an assumption.
Feel free to re-tag or edit if necessary or appropriate.

Under joint measurability of $v$, this is just a part of the proof of Fubini/Tonelli's Theorem. You could consider the case when $g$ and $v$ are non-negative and then consider linear combinations.

@geetha290krm Oh, that would indeed work, and you could apply it to the positive and negative parts of $gv$ directly. Thanks for the kind comment!

Thanks to geetha's kind comment above, it's actually fairly simple.
Assume that $v$ is jointly measurable, so that $gv$ is jointly measurable for all $g \in L^{p^\ast}(D)$.
Then, by (the proof of) the Fubini-Tonelli theorem applied to the positive and negative parts $(gv)^+$ and $(gv)^-$ of $gv$, which are jointly measurable and non-negative, the maps $t \in E \mapsto \int_D (gv)^\pm(x,t) \mathrm{d} x$ are measurable, and so $G$ is measurable as a linear combination of measurable functions.
